# 3 phase panel board

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

I am testing a three-phase panel board with separate neutral and earth bars. I removed the main neutral from the neutral bar, but found that some light or a/c area they connect earth instead of neutral with phase. How can I identify the location where the connected the same? (Our contractor made so many mistakes that they looped the neutral to earth point in some sockets.)

Comment: Where are you located? WHY are you "tasting" this panel?

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: The type of voltage and transformer connections would be needed to provide the proper grounding locations (120/208, delta, wye are clues we would need). If the 3 phase is not balanced well there may be larger than normal neutral voltages due to the unbalanced loads on the 3 phase transformer. Removing the neutral can be dangerous depending on the type of connections, I have seen Delta's fry electrical equipment on the low voltage side when the neutral was damaged.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry.  But having done this for a whole factory, there is simply no substitute for opening up every electrical box and testing everything.

However this may help.

Keep in mind if you own the transformers, the entire electrical system (neutral included) floats at whatever bias to ground you choose, *or none at all* - some systems are intentionally isolated from ground.  Most of the time, people choose 0 volt bias with a thick copper wire, so it's easy to forget this bias can be anything you want.

Remember, **power doesn't want to go to ground, it wants to go back to source.**  It only wants to go to ground *if* ground will get it to source via your neutral-ground strap.  In an isolated system, a single system-ground fault doesn't want to go to ground at all, since ground does not lead anywhere it would want (since it's isolated).  In fact, the ground fault acts like the grounding strap/bond, and ends up only de-isolating the system and giving it a bias.  A second ground fault would cause current to flow.

In an isolated system, you detect undesired grounds with a ground relay.  It's like a ground strap, except it makes several hundred turns around a coil.  Now, when a ground-fault happens, there's somewhere to go to get back to source - through the ground relay TRIP!  There should never be any current moving through the ground relay.  But then, there should never be any current on a neutral-ground strap either.

So here's what I would do for testing.  Improvise a "ground relay" by replacing your neutral-ground bond/strap with a longer wire that loops a couple times, and put a clamp-meter around that.  Now turn on one circuit at a time, and turn on every single thing on that circuit, and have a helper call out if they see anything more than 0.000 amps.

Any current flow on the ground strap proves a ground fault.  It may well be what you're looking for - but it could also be something unexpected.

Another testing method is kinda brassy, but it involves replacing the neutral-ground bond *with an intentional bias*, so neutral is *other than* 0V from ground.  What if you replaced the neutral-bond strap with a car battery? (don't.) But how about a 6V buck/boost transformer, the kind you use to bump a distant service a few volts.  That adds a 6 volt AC bias between neutral and ground. Hot-ground voltages will now be 4 or 6 volts more or less than they should be -- but, hot-neutral should be equal regardless of the bias neutral-ground. This won't detect regular ground faults, just miswire jobs.